# Spark iterative program has linear memory consumption

Tags: scala, apache-spark, memory, memory-leaks, threadpool

I am running a relatively simple Spark program, on a 6 nodes cluster, iterating over a list of indices, each iteration taking around 2-3min.

A good idea seemed to parallelize over the list of indices with a fixed thread pool count and with a FAIR scheduling: `spark.scheduler.mode=FAIR`.

The code being:

```
val df1 = spark.read.parquet("....")
val df2 = spark.read.parquet("....")

val parIndices = indices.par
parIndices.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new ForkJoinPool(3))

parIndices.foreach(index => {
    val df = df1
        .where($"id".between(index, index + 100))
        .joinWith(df2, condition, "inner")
        .map {
            case (left: Type1, right: Type2) => (
                left.id,
                right.id,
                left.distance(right)
            )
        }.toDF()

    df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(s"$basePath/index=$index")
})
```

However, what is happening is that the memory resources of the cluster seem to not be released whatsoever, causing a linear consumption of the memory and eventually hogging the cluster ram after 1 hour of processing.

[image: memory consumption]

It may be worth noting that I'm using Spark 2.4.4 on EMR 5.29 and Scala 2.11.12.

Any idea what could cause this? or how to debug this?

Comment: Since the Dataframe map is invoked inside parallel indices, this two-layer parallelism might be hogging the cluster, as multiple Dataframe join & map operation will be invoked simultaneously. 1) Could you please check the performance with a sequential foreach or 2) Instead use Spark APIs to perform the foreach logic that is bulk join on the entire Datafame and then select & write data for the indexs.

Comment: Hi @hagarwal - 1) it is fairly constant on an index range. 2) This is unfortunately not an option, as the operations and join products are simply too big to fit in the cluster (even after simplifying join conditions by removing `OR`s and replacing them by unions then `dropDuplicates`).